# How to mock private member variable depending on a service call

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to mock an object of DataClient class in Java. I am not sure how to mock s3 member variable here. I came from ruby background and we have something called rspec-mock where we don't need to mock instance variables.

```
public class DataClient {

  private String userName, bucket, region, accessKey, secretKey;
  private AmazonS3Client s3;

  public OdwClient(String accessKey, String secretKey, String userName, String bucket, String region){
    this.accessKey = accessKey;
    this.accessKey = secretKey;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.bucket = bucket;
    this.region = region;
    this.s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
  }

  public boolean pushData(String fileName) {
    s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", fileName, new File("filePath")).
    return true;
  }
}
```

All I have tried now is in tests is:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
      DataClient client = Mockito.mock(DataClient.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPushData() {
      // I don't know how to mock s3.putObject() method here
    }
```

My tests keeps failing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is because you are not using dependency injection. The whole idea behind mocking is that you create mocked objects for external dependencies. In order to do that, you need to provide those external dependencies to your object. This can be done as constructor argument, or a parameter, or via a dependency injection framework.

Here's how you could rewrite your class to be more testable:

```
public class DataClient {

  private String userName, bucket, region, accessKey, secretKey;
  private AmazonS3Client s3;

  public OdwClient(String accessKey, String secretKey, String userName, String bucket, String region){
    this(accessKey, secretKey, userName, bucket, region, new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
  }

  public OdwClient(String accessKey, String secretKey, String userName, String bucket, String region, AmazonS3Client s3){
    this.accessKey = accessKey;
    this.accessKey = secretKey;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.bucket = bucket;
    this.region = region;
    this.s3 = s3;
  }

  public boolean pushData(String fileName) {
    s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", fileName, new File("filePath")).
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then you can use a real `DataClient` instance instead of a mock, and mock the s3 instance for the new DataClient constructor. After you mock the `AmazonS3Client` instance, you can use typical mocking tools to provide expected responses from its methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerMock extension to mock the instantiation of AmazonS3Client  class. Something along the line of

```
myMockedS3Client = Mockito.mock(AmazonS3Client.class)
PowerMockito.whenNew(AmazonS3Client.class).thenReturn(myMockedS3Client)
```

Comment: Don't you mean **PowerMockito.whenNew**?